# How do I create a plot with probability in R?

Tags: r, plot

How do I store probability in R?

I was thinking of creating a log-odds model but I do not know how to store probability.

Data: `RegFG`

Fitted model:

```
 mylogit <- glm(Result \~ kickLength, data = RegFg, family = "binomial")
```

This is my plot so far but, as I stated before, I am unsure how to calculate probability.

```
plot.dat <- data.frame(prob = ?,

kl = RegFg$kickLength,

fit = predict(mylogit, RegFg))

plot.dat$fit\_prob <- exp(plot.dat$fit)/(1+exp(plot.dat$fit))

ggplot(plot.dat, aes(x=kl, y=prob)) +

geom\_point() +

geom\_line(aes(x=kl, y=fit\_prob))
```

Comment: Can you share a subset of your data set with `dput(data)`?

Comment: Yes. Which subset should I share?

Comment: Your main data set, `RegFg` if that's the one.